# mongodb count unique constraint on 2 fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

On my car mongodb collection I have user_id and default_car fields. One user can have only one default car but can have multiple non-default cars. For instance this value should be valid :

```
[{user_id:1,default_car:true},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:true},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:false},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:false}]
```

user with id 1 has only one car but user with id 2 has 3 cars and one of them is the default one. This example should be invalid :

```
 [{user_id:1,default_car:true},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:true},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:true},{user_id:2,defaut_tool:false}]
```

What kind of constraint Do I need to define ? I use mongoose on nodejs.

Comment: Do the arrays you've provided represent four documents in the collection? Or is that entire array intended to be embedded in a single document (and what would that document be logically)?

Comment: @user20042973 they represent four documents in the collection. Each one is a different document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to satisfy a uniqueness constraint within MongoDB, then you will want to look into [unique indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/).

In your particular situation, it sounds like the uniqueness constraint should be enforced is that each specific `user_id` cannot have more than one `default_car`. Therefore you your index should also be a [partial index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/). Specifically the index should probably resemble the following:

```
db.<collectionName>.createIndex({_user_id:1},{unique:true, partialFilterExpression:{default_car:true}})
```